# Integration of Alipay with Shopify: Are there any plugins or alternatives to the official documentation?

Tags: shopify, alipay

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to integrate Alipay as a payment gateway with Shopify. While I have come across the official documentation on Shopify for [payment gateways](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/payments), I'm wondering if there are any additional plugins or alternative solutions available for this specific integration.

Has anyone had experience with this or can recommend a third-party solution or plugin that allows for a seamless integration of Alipay with Shopify?

The store is registered outside Asia so I need alternative solution rather than  [Alipay (Direct)](https://www.chinafy.com/blog/alipay-on-shopify-how-to-integrate-alipay-on-shopify) from 'Alternative Payment Providers' under 'Settings'.

Thank you in advance for your insights!